# Where can I find those visual effect demonstration?

Tags: rendering, shader

I'm studying Unreal Engine, this chapter is talk about visual effects: [Rendering Overview](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Rendering/Overview)

Some of them has obvious picture I can see whats the differences. But not all of them. Is there a site can let me input the keyword, like 'bloom', then it shows the description, a image contains 'no bloom' and 'has bloom' both?

Answer (score 3):

The Unreal Engine documentation has good explanations for their various post-processing effects like Bloom. You can find more information about it here: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Rendering/PostProcessEffects/Bloom

In the case of UE4, bloom becomes observable once color values push beyond the 1.0 value.

Comment: You can also turn lots of things on and off in UE4 itself, using the ['Show' menu in the editor viewports](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/UI/LevelEditor/Viewports/ShowFlags).

Comment: @mbl 'bloom' is an example, not my real confusing effect.

Something like 'Sub-Surface Shading' or 'Ambient Occlusion', I can hardly tell what effect exactly it shows when with or without it.